# Email Address Validation Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I want to set up an Email Address Validation Regex with the following constraints...
reference:   `α` @ `β` . `γ`

for `α`
1) Only contain `a-z`  `0-9` `.` `-` `_`
2) Contain between 1 and 30 chars (inclusive)
3) Can't start or end with `.` `-` `_`
4) Can't have 2 consecutive symbols (out of `.` `-` `_`)  in it

for `β`
1) Only contain `a-z`  `0-9` `-`
2) Contain between 2 and 14 chars (inclusive)
3) Can't start or end with `-`
4) Can't have 2 consecutive `-`  in it

for `γ`
1) Only contain `a-z`
2) Contain between 2 and 4 chars (inclusive)

===========================================================================

The first two constraints of each are easy to implement, So I have done it, as follows
`([a-z0-9.\-_]{1,30})@([a-z0-9\-]{2,14}).([a-z]{2,4})`

Can anyone help me with (2) and (3) of `α` and `β`

Comment: Do you specifically want only those be valid that meet those criteria? Or is this the best approximation you came up with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Just test for an `@` and a dot `.` after the `@`. Anything else is useless. To verify the mail address send a valdiation mail to that address.

Comment: Try `^(?=[^@]{1,30}@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*@(?=.{2,14}\.[a-z]+$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9-])*\.[a-z]{2,4}$`. However, it does not allow `.-` or `.-` or `-._` in the username part which is not mentioned in the requirements.

Comment: `^(?=[^@]{1,30}@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*@(?=.{2,14}\.[a-z]+$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9-])*\.[a-z]{2,4}$` works for `α` but it breaks when `-` is added to `β`

Comment: The best way to validate an email address is to send an email and check the return value. 
Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: @GaurangiS I think there is a typo, use `^(?=[^@\n]{1,30}@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*@(?=.{2,14}\.[a-z]+$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9])*\.[a-z]{2,4}$` if you test at a regex tester. See a [regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/nAUcIv/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=[^@]{1,30}@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*@(?=.{2,14}\.[a-z]+$)[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAUcIv/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[^@]{1,30}@)` - 1 to 30 chars are allowed before a `@`
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1+ lowercase letters and digits
- `(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of `.`, `_` or `-` followed with 1+ lowercase letters or digits
- `@` - a `@` char
- `(?=.{2,14}\.[a-z]+$)` - immediately to the right, there must be 2 to 14 chars, then `.` and 1+ lowercase letters till the end of string
- `[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*` - 1+ lowercase letters and digits and then 0 or more occurrences of a hyphen followed with 1+ lowercase letters or digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `[a-z]{2,4}` - two to four lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: EVERYTHING else works fine EXCEPT the case of `-` in `β`

Comment: @GaurangiS See https://regex101.com/r/nAUcIv/3. There was another typo.